# How do I identify the Initial Catalog(name of the collection database) in a migrating step of Azure DevOps Server to Services?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am an administrator of Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 in an organization.
I will migrate our collection from the on-premises server to Azure DevOps Services.
Currently, I am on the step of using SqlPackage.exe to generate a DACPAC file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops

According to this reference, the command example to generate DACPAC is as below.

```
SqlPackage.exe /sourceconnectionstring:"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Foo;Integrated Security=True" /targetFile:C:\DACPAC\Foo.dacpac /action:extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true /p:IgnorePermissions=true /p:Storage=Memory
```

However, I cannot understand what is Initial Catalog.
The reference said `Initial Catalog - Name of the collection database.`
But I could not find the name of the collection database in Azure DevOps Server management console.

I referred another article on dev.to
https://dev.to/timothymcgrath/the-great-azure-devops-migration-part-6-import-2obc
By this article, `Initial Catalog=[COLLECTION_NAME]`,
and the collection name in my Azure DevOps Server is "DefaultCollection" (default name).

Then, I tried the following command then failed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130> ./SqlPackage.exe /sourceconnectionstring:”Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DefaultCollection;Integrated Security=True” /targetFile:C:\DefaultCollection.dacpac /action:extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true /p:IgnorePermissions=true /p:Storage=Memory
Connecting to database 'DefaultCollection' on server 'localhost'.
Extracting schema
Extracting schema from database
*** Error extracting database:Could not connect to database server.

(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40
```

Is this error caused by wrong Initial Catalog?
How do I find the correct Initial Catalog - Name of the collection database?

## Environment and pre-conditions

- Windows 10 Pro
- SqlPackage.exe installed from SSDT for Visual Studio 2017
- The machine where commands are executed and where Azure DevOps Server running is the same

  - so, `DataSource=localhost` should be correct, I think
- Detached my collection by Azure DevOps Server management console
- SQL Server Express for my Azure DevOps server is running

Comment: the name of the collection in Management Console is usually the name of the database catalog, maybe prefixed with tfs_. If this is not the case, try using sql server management studio to connect to the server and find out the names of the catalgos-collections.

Comment: I tried SQL Server Management Studio.
Successfully connected to the database and found the name "AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
The database name in the case is "AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection".
It could be found by Azure DevOps Management Console in the feature of selecting attach. (Application Tier -> Team Project Collections)
Or, by using SQL Server Management Studio, we can also find "AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection".

And, in my case, `DataSource=localhost` is wrong, `DataSource=<hostname>\SQLEXPRESS` is correct.
I noticed this answer when I connect to my database by SQL Server Management Studio.
Finally, I successfully generated a DACPAC file.

```
Connecting to database 'AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection' on server '<my machine host name>\SQLEXPRESS'.
Extracting schema
Extracting schema from database
Resolving references in schema model
Validating schema model for data package
Validating schema
Exporting data from database
Exporting data
Processing Export.
Processing Table '[dbo].[tbl_PropertyValue]'.
Processing Table '[Task].[tbl_LibraryItemString]'.
...
...
...
Processing Table '[Search].[tbl_FileMetadataStore]'.
Processing Table '[dbo].[SequenceIds]'.
Successfully extracted database and saved it to file 'C:\DACPAC\DefaultCollection.dacpac'.
```

Thanks so much! Mario Dietner, Daniel Mann.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the admin console on your app tier. That shows you all of the databases.

For what it's worth, the standard name for the default collection database is `Tfs_DefaultCollection`. It may be different in your case, but that's a safe bet.

Comment: I found the database name "AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection" in Azure DevOps Mangement Console on the selecting attach feature.
At, first I wrote
```
I could not find the name of the collection database in Azure DevOps Server management console.
```
but, it is my mistake. You are right. Thank you.